# "... joy of giving presents" VS "....joy of the giving of presents"

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, passive-voice

**"For others, it will be the joy of fellowship and the giving of presents."** [King's christmas speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgUunxUH3yw) (see:1:17-1:22)

The expression **"... the giving of the presents"** caught my attention, because we generally say **"...giving presents".**, and he could have said **"...the joy of fellowship and giving presents".**, but there must a reason he used it in a passive structure **"the doing of something"** rather than **"doing something".**

So, did he say **"....the giving of presents."** to emphasize its ceremonial aspect and the mutual exchange of presents rather than one side simply giving something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be interpreted two ways:

> The joy of [fellowship and giving presents] OR
>
> [The joy of fellowship] and [the giving of presents] (two different aspects of Christmas).

It's my guess that King Charles intended the second meaning.